# I have installed styled-components into my React project but getting an error

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

When running the virtual DOM it keeps throwing this error.

Failed to compile.

> ./node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve
> '/Users/benjohnson/Desktop/ListProject/my-app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js'
> in '/Users/benjohnson/Desktop/ListProject/my-app'

Comment: I Think Installation having the problem.
npm install --save styled-components

Comment: Thanks mate re ran it again and it sorted it out. Not sure what was happening there.

Comment: @Brett01 You have Raushan's answer down there, it would be nice of you if you upvoted his answer and checked it as a solution, since man helped you. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

I Think Installation having the problem. npm install --save styled-components

Answer (score 2):

Please, try to close the react project and then npm start again. Hope, it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you needed was to add .js to my extension resolve in webpack.config.js

Answer (score 0):

step1(optional): update npm `sudo npm install -g npm`

step2 : delete node-modules folder `rm -rf node-modules`

step3 : run `npm install`